# Vertical Align is Wrong in UI Kit Navbar and Buttons

Tags: css, user-interface, button, uikit, navbar

I've noticed that the text in the navbar links and in buttons are all vertically aligned a little too high. I used the code out of the box and noticed that on the UI Kit website it looks fine. I used Chrome while checking both sites. Can anyone compare my code with theirs and see what's going on? My code can be found at http://culturehog.com

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Actually, on [UIkit website](https://getuikit.com/) it doesn't look fine, text is also a little bit too high and I believe it's a matter of used font.

Comment: Hmm... Well right on my homepage you can see the text is too high, especially in relation to the Font Awesome icons on the top. So, I guess regardless if it's a UI Kit thing, does anyone know how to bump it down or center it? I tried adding padding to the top which works but then the background hover color looks a little cut off on the top. I guess it's not the end of the world if no one can help. Thanks for trying!